# Rails form inline errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a large form with a lot of fields, The way we get back errors in rails is that the they reside inside the model object. i want a clean way to show errors besides each field instead of showing the separately. Is there a gem that can do this and if now what can be the best way to do it.

I want each error to show besides the field the error is on.

Comment: Get the errors for each field (`@object.errors[field_name]`) and iterate over them in the form. I think some of the form gems do this, but I'm not sure which one(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `simple_form` or `formtastic` to make this easier. With those, it'll automatically do what you're looking for.

If you want to make your views really long, or just don't want to use a gem, you can also do this:

`<span class="help-inline"><%= @object.errors[:field] %></span>`

But that'll get icky fast.

Comment: It's not icky at all, but you should iterate over them (or use a helper) since it's a collection-per-field.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using Rails 3+ and the Rails Form Helpers, you do not need any gems and you do not need to iterate over the errors collection.

Well, that's not entirely true, but Rails does it for you. You just need to provide a proc.

I add the following to  .../config/application.rb:

```
# wrap each form field that has an error with the following. 
# note, condition for arrays and singletons.
config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  if instance.error_message.kind_of?(Array)
    %(<span class="validation-error">#{html_tag}</span>).html_safe
  else
    %(#{html_tag}<span class="validation-error">&nbsp;</span>).html_safe
  end
end
```

Make sure to define the CSS class validation-error. That should get it working, then you can tweak it to fit your needs. Note, your CSS can be specific to each field type, e.g., input, textarea, select, etc.

And of course restart the Rails app.

I actually learned this in another thread on SO, but I can't find it now so I can't provide the reference.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but is there a way to pull this out into the lib folder as a class or something. Code in application.rb is not really in the best interest of maintenance